# Repeat only part of model with a while loop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

The first part of my model isolates roads in a jurisdiction and then the second part of my model selects the roads in the jurisdiction that are greater than 500m and splits them.

I've input a while iterator to continue if any of the roads are greater than 500m but I'd like it to only apply to the second part of the model and ignore the first part. Is this possible?

EDIT: In order to simplify things I split the section I'd like to include in the while loop into its own section. The problem now is the input is not being updated so after each iteration the number of sections over 500m resets.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're making it too complicated.

All you need to do is

`DATA -> MAKE FEATURE LAYER -> DO THE DESIRED GEOPROCESSING`

Okay, so check out [Make Feature Layer - Arc Help](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006p000000).

You will be using the optional 'where clause' argument.  In this argument you put your selection for `"LENGTH" > 500`.

Now your model will select only lines meeting that requirement and bring them to the geoprocessing stage where you can do your splitting.

Comment: I don't see how the Make Feature Layer tool is going to help here. To simplify things I've isolated the while loop into a separate model. The problem is the model doesn't update the input feature class so after each iteration the number of sections over 500m resets. See here http://i.imgur.com/gIkB58E.png

Comment: I guess I'm not totally sure what you are trying to do.  You are taking a line layer, and you want to split it into lines no larger than 500m?  Why not just do `DISSOLVE` using the distance argument?  This will do all of that automatically.  No complex model or while iteration needed,

Comment: Would you mind expanding on how one would use Dissolve to split lines greater than a certain distance? I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: Oops, mistyped (answering too many questions at once :) ).  I meant to say `DENSIFY`.  See [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001v00000003000000.htm) -- `densification_method` would be distance, and distance would be 500.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. The files I have are in GCS_North_American_1983_CSRS so I'm not sure what the Shape_Length field represents. I can't find a way of tying Distance to the LENGTH_GEO field I calculated using Add Geometric Attributes